# Is the Van der Pol equation stiff for initial value y(0)=1?

Tags: numerical-methods, dynamical-systems

I'm working on a task for my Numerical Analysis class which is about stiff equations.

We're asked to implement several algorithms to solve the Van der Pol equation with varying parameters and initial values $y(0) = 1$ and $y'(0)=0$.

When I linearize the problem by estimating the eigenvalues of $f(t,[x_1,x_2]) = (x_2,\mu(1-x_1^2)x_2+x_1)$, it turns out that with this configuration the eigenvalues are always estimated to be $\lambda \simeq \pm 1$:

$D_xf(t,x)=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
-2 \mu x_1x_2 +1 & \mu(1-x_1^2)
\end{pmatrix}$

Setting $x_1 \approx y(0) \approx 1$, $x_2 \approx y'(0) \approx 0$ will always yield \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}

Am I mistaken here? Or did the professor make a mistake? Because the exercise really revolves around stiff equations, so it would be pointless if we don't have this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equation seems to have some sign errors. The second order formulation is based on an harmonic oscillator with friction term (for large $x$), $$\ddot x+μ(x^2-1)\dot x+x=0.$$ Thus your matrix should be $\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0}$, giving a rotational segments, locally.

The stiffness occurs for larger $\mu$ on the limit cycle, at the passing from the fast to the slow region of the system. The initial point is just some point inside the limit cycle that is not the equilibrium at the origin. See for instance https://stackoverflow.com/a/60362575/3088138 for one consequence of this stiffness.

Comment: This was the equation in the task, apparently the professor made a mistake. Thank you very much sir!

Comment: if I may ask a follow up question: the eigenvalues of the corrected matrix you gave are $i $ and $-i$, so in this case you would still not have stiffness regardless of the parameter, no?

Comment: That is correct, the stiffness comes from the middle term, especially prominently at the points $(x,x')=(\pm3,0)$ with Jacobian $\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&-3\mu}$, with eigenvalues at about $-3\mu$, $-1/(3\mu)$ for large $\mu$.

Comment: Why would the matrix entry on the lower right be $-3 \mu$? Wouldn't you have $\mu (1-3^2)= - 8 \mu$? (Apologies if I seem pedantic, I'm just very anxious to understand correctly).

Comment: Sorry, the point should have $x=\pm2$.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for your time sir, it has been very helpful!